# How to get running logloss in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a model batch by batch. The training goal is to minimize the batch log loss. When I test the model, batches are used as well. For accuracy and AUC, I can use `tf.metrics.auc` and `tf.matrics.accuracy` to get running accuracy and AUC. However, how can I get running logloss for the test data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a running metric from any metric `M` by calling `tf.metrics.mean(M)`.

For example,

```
my_loss = tf.losses.log_loss(labels, predictions)
my_running_loss, update_op = tf.metrics.mean(my_loss)
```

Comment: There is no tf.metrics.logloss. Do you mean using M=tf.losses.logloss and tf.metrics.mean(M)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I edited my answer to make that clearer.